# Windows serial port drivers - registry

Tags: c, windows, serial-port, registry, inf

Can anyone please explain what is the significance of:

```
HKR,,"95xSpecific",%REG_BINARY%,01,00,00,00,00,00,c9,16,20,00,01,00,00,00,00,00,08,00,00,00,00,40,00,10
```

Above is the snippet of the **.inf** file of driver. How to understand it in separate terms.

Comment: This registry node is not standard and the corresponding driver will read and decode this value internally. If you do not have the sources of this driver then you can't decode this value.

Comment: How to decode tell me I have sources as well. I am just a beginner with windows drivers help me.